# How to add apt-keys with puppet?

Tags: puppet, apt

Using this [puppet-module for apt](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apt), how can i import this key:

```
https://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg
```

What i want to achieve is a puppet-related solution for both shell commands:

```
wget https://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg
apt-key add dotdeb.gpg
```

The documentation of this puppet-modul isn't clear about this. How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use apt::key

https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apt/blob/master/manifests/key.pp

something like this in your hiera -

```
  apt::keys:
      varnish-3.0:
        key: C4DEFFEB
        key_source: http://repo.varnish-cache.org/debian/GPG-key.txt
```

https://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/4845/add-key-with-puppetlabs-apt/

or in your puppet manifest file -

```
apt::key {'HEXKEYID':
  source => 'https://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg',
  id     => 'ID_OF_YOUR_KEY'
}
```

Comment: In the manifestfile, it gives an error: Error: validate_re(): "dotdeb" does not match ["\\A(0x)?[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\\Z", "\\A(0x)?[0-9a-fA-F]{16}\\Z", "\\A(0x)?[0-9a-fA-F]{40}\\Z"]

Comment: @AnshuPrateek How do I get the HEXKEYID?
and also the "id  =>"

Comment: @AnshuPrateek I also am curious on how to obtain the hex id of a key.

Comment: @anudeep  You can use the apt-key list to find the name of the key (thats the key id in hex).

Comment: @ElliotLabs comments allow only one user mention, see above.

Comment: One way to get the HexKeyID in the 0xlong format is to use the following command with the keyfile `gpg --keyid-format 0xlong --verbose --dry-run --import KEYFILE`

The output will contain a string in the format that matches the required, `["\\A(0x)?[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\\Z", "\\A(0x)?[0-9a-fA-F]{16}\\Z", "\\A(0x)?[0-9a-fA-F]{40}\\Z"]` that passes validation.